# How can I quote back-tics in a bash function?

Tags: bash

I want a function in my .bash_profile like this:

```
function usb() {
    cd `pwd`
}
```

But when I run that, it does not go to the current directory, it goes to my home directory. I tried quoting the back-tics a few different ways, but could not figure it out.

Comment: `cd .`? Maybe `cd $PWD`? ... but why would you want to do this? If you want to quote them (again, I don't understand why), single-quotes work fine...but that's kind of useless unless you have a directory named '\`pwd\`'.

Comment: The only way that would go to your home directory is if 1) `pwd` produced no output (or whitespace-only output), or 2) you were already in your home directory.

Comment: If my cwd is in a dir on a usb drive. When I plug the drive back in, I get `ls: .: No such file or directory` even though the drive is back. But you are right `cd .` works just fine. I will crawl in a hole now.  But as to the question single-quotes did not work, can you give the exact answer? So doing it at a shell does work, with no quoting, it goes to the cwd and fixes the stale directory problem. But yes `cd .` is a lot smarter. I think it's still a valid question, how do you quote back-tics in a bash function.

Comment: What single quotes? Do you mean ``'`pwd`'``? Single quotes prevent command substitution just as they do parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into *why* you would want to write this function, it should look like

```
usb () {
    cd "$(pwd)"
}
```

`` usb () { "`pwd`"; } `` would work, but `$(...)` is generally preferred over `` `...` ``.

Comment: Oh that's cool, didn't know $(foo) ran a command. But it doesn't work on my mac, `bash 3.2.57(1)` I check my function is exactly like you have it using `declare -f` and it still goes back to home. But yes `cd .` is 1000x better solution. But still wondering how to do this, but just out of curiosity at this point.

Comment: This is probably related your current directory being unmounted when you unplug the USB drive, not anything to do with `bash` syntax.

Comment: Typing it directly into the shell works fine, but it doesn't work as a function. Now `cd .` works, but the quoting question was not answered.

Comment: Mmmm, okay both quoted versions work, in that they maintain the quotes. But the `cd` fails. Here I show the two failing and then typing in the shell works: https://imgur.com/a/LGMSUF1 But not I think we are into completely useless territory, I think the quoting works and the $(command) was nice to learn.

Comment: If `pwd` produces an error message (to standard error) instead of an actual directory (to standard output), then there is no output to capture with the back-tics, and the unquoted command substitution simply disappears, leaving you with the command `cd`, with no arguments.

Comment: Interesting. But why should it produce an error when typing it in the shell works? As shown in the image. Haha.

Comment: Why are you quoting the entire command in that image? `cd "$(pwd)"`, not `"cd $(pwd)"`.

Comment: OMG that was dumb. Okay all 4 methods work: `usb1`, `usb2`, `cd pwd` (but in back-tics) and `cd .`. See https://imgur.com/a/nBkBw7N Answer accepted, thanks guys. Bash is so good but so foreign to me.